# Change log file half way thru execution

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tech: Python 3.11.3

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    filename="logFilePath.log",
    format=loggingFormat,
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p",
    style="%",
)
```

have a `my_logger.py` class that has this snippet in it's `__init__` and I made sure to initialize the `my_logger` at the very beginning of the module entry. I use this `logger` in several classes and it writes stuff to file and console. Life is good

But now I want to separate the log files for each "task" that the script does. Something like this

```py
for task in ["task1", "task2", "task3"]:
    logger.info(f"this line is written to {task}.log file")
```

so there will be 3 different log files - `task1.log`, `task2.log`, `task3.log`, and so on

but can't really figure out how to set this up. I tried setting just `logging.basicConfig(filename=task)` at the beginning of each for loop, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: The `filename` is used to configure the single `FileHandler` attached to the root logger. You should use three different loggers, each with its own handler for the appropriate file, and use the appropriate logger for each message.

Comment: `for logger in [task1_logger, task2_logger, task3_logger]: logger.info("...")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of log handler with custom formatting, changing output file during execution:

```
"""Example of logging to separate files in custom format"""

import logging
import time

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class LoggingFormatterTZISO(logging.Formatter):
    """Customized logging.Formatter using ISO-8601 timestamp with tz"""

    default_time_format: str = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
    default_msec_format: str = "%s.%03d"
    default_tz_format: str = "%z"

    def formatTime(self, record: logging.LogRecord, datefmt: str | None = None) -> str:
        """Format asctime from record.created adding ms and tz offset suffix"""
        if datefmt is None:
            datefmt = self.default_time_format
        converted_record = self.converter(record.created)
        timestamp_formatted = time.strftime(datefmt, converted_record)
        timezone_formatted = time.strftime(self.default_tz_format, converted_record)
        return f"{self.default_msec_format}{timezone_formatted}" % (
            timestamp_formatted,
            record.msecs,
        )


log_formatter = LoggingFormatterTZISO("%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s")

for task in ["task1", "task2", "task3"]:
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(f"{task}.log")
    file_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    root_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logging.info("this line is written to %s.log file", task)
    root_logger.removeHandler(file_handler)
```